# Automatic Variables Name Suggestion in Qt-Creator

Tags: ide, qt-creator

Would it be possible to configure QtCreator to automatically suggest names for a given variable?

For example, when writing a name for a variable as a private member of a class, I will use a coding standard:

```
ClassName className_;
```

So I am looking for a way to instruct Qt-Creator to automatically suggest className_ as variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried experimenting with [Code Snippets](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-completing-code.html#editing-code-snippets)?

For instance you could setup a snippet of:

```
$var$ $var:l$_;
```

Which when triggered would: insert a given word, followed by the word in all lower case, followed by an underscore and then semicolon.

For example, I assigned the above to the trigger mv:

[image: Snippets Menu]

Which mean in the desired location I can:

1. Type: **mv**
2. Press: **cntrl+space**
3. Press: **tab**
4. Type: **ClassName**
5. Press: **enter**

Comment: Thank you for replying. What if I want to get className_ instead of ClassName_ as variable name? I mean, lower camel case instead of upper camel case.

Comment: As far as I can tell no :/ which is quite odd since they supply a way to make the first character upper case but not lower case `:c converts the initial letter of the string to upper case`. It might be worth suggesting a change request on their [bug reporter](https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/QTCREATORBUG)?

Comment: But that makes the whole variable lower case right?